# Prevent User From Triggering Multiple Scrolling

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have a `HomePageContainers` which holds the data for the AJAX requests and pass down to `HomePage` component. `HomePage` component is composed via an higher order function `InfiniteScroll` which supports scrolling.

The `InfiniteScroll` looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), false);
}

onScroll() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= (document.body.offsetHeight - 200)) {
        const { scrollFunc } = this.props;
        scrollFunc();
    }
}
```

I want the code to prevent scrolling once they fired one and wait till the data arrives from the request. Something like:

```
 ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= (document.body.offsetHeight - 200)) + //a new condition to make sure only scroll happens when data arrives or fails.
```

Note that the `scrollFunc` will be received from `HomePageContainers` which is going to update its state according to AJAX request/responses.

I can store the scrolling state in `HomePageContainers` as @Igorsvee mentioned but I want those state to go to `InfiniteScroll` component as its responsible for handling the scrolling events.

How will I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `HomePageContainers` component issues ajax requests, you could add a new `isFetching` flag to it's state and pass it down along with `scrollFunc` so that you can conditionally invoke it:

```
if(this.props.isFetching){
   scrollFunc();
}
```

`isFetching` should be `true` when a request starts, `false` when it ends with success or error. 
Or you could have the conditional logic inside the `scrollFunc`itself:

```
if(this.state.isFetching){
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah this way I can do it. `HomePageContainers` is just for handling the data. So the sate will be equal to AJAX response state. Was thinking whether its a good idea to have scrolling data in `HomePageContainers` as have `InfiniteScroll` separately which is responsible for scrolling and its activity (for which I feel its bad) .